# Scala: Maintain child class in parent methods?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, return-current-type

When you have a parent:

```
abstract class Parent {
   def something(arg: ???): Parent = ???
}
```

and

```
class Child extends Parent {}
```

I would like

```
val updatedChild = new Child().something(...)
```

`updatedChild` to be of type `Child` and not of type `Parent`, is it possible ?

Comment: BTW, [this blog post](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html) by **tpolecat** covers exactly this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it, is to parametrize the parent:

```
 abstract class Parent[T <: Parent[T]] {
    def something(arg: Foo): T
 }

 class Child(val foo: String) extends Parent[Child] {
    def something(arg: String) = return new Child(arg)
 }
```

Sometimes, you can also get away with using `this.type`:

```
class Parent {
  def something(arg: Foo): this.type = this
}
class Child {
   override def something(arg: Foo) = this
}
```

But the latter method only works if all you ever want to return is `this` (`this.type` is not `Parent` or `Child`, but a specific type that only has one instance - `this`).

Comment: I am not sure I understand what is the catch with `this.type` , could you elaborate on that in your answer ? thanks !

Comment: The catch is you won't be able to return `new Child()` only `this`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposal that *actually compiles*:

```
abstract class Parent[Repr <: Parent[Repr]] {
  def something(arg: Int): Repr
}
```

This is something you *can* do, at least it's not explicitly discouraged. Standard collection library uses it a lot, see e.g. [IterableLike](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/IterableLike.html) as a typical example of such F-bounded polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks , I updated my answer. Forgot it haha. @Dima should also update his.

Comment: @Wonay Yeah, whatever... Everyone's too busy celebrating, so they're all posting non-compiling code, apparently :]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can do :

```
class Parent[THIS <: Parent[THIS]] {
   def something: THIS
}
```

And that seems to work.

I am not sure if this is something you should do tho.

Answer (score 1):

Both Andrey's and Dima's answers cover one way to solve the problem using only oo-patterns.

However I would like to point out another approach called **typeclasses** *(which is more common in functional languages)*, that would be helpful if you are planning to write generic functions using your interface.

First, instead of having a parent class, you have an *interface* that describes the operations that can be performed on instances of the typeclass.

```
trait Typeclass[T] {
  def something(t: T)(arg: Foo): T
}
```

Then, you would define your types, this time they don't extend any parent class, thus they don't have to override nothing.

```
class Child {
  ...
}
```

Now, you have to prove that your type is an instance of the type class.
*(A common place to do that is in the companion object of the class)*.

```
object Child {
  implicit final val ChildTypeclass: Typeclass[Child] = new Typeclass[Child] {
    override def something(child: Child)(arg: Foo): Child = ???
  }
}
```

Finally, you define a generic method that can operate on any type T as long as there is an instance of your typeclass for that type.

```
def generic[T](t: T, arg: Foo)(implicit tt: Typeclass[T]): T =
  tt.something(t)(arg)
```

Bonus, if you want to recover the *"dot notation"* you can add an Ops pattern to your Typeclass.

```
object syntax {
  object typeclass {
     implicit final class TypeclassOps[T](val t: T) extends AnyVal {
       final def something(arg: Foo)(implicit tt: Typelcass[T]) =
         tt.something(t)(arg)
     }
  }
}

import syntax.typeclasss._

def generic[T: Typelcass](t: T, arg: Foo): T
  t.something(arg)

val newChild = generic(new Child, new Foo)
// newChild: Child = ???
```

Also, a common approach is to define the `something` method in your class and the typeclass instance forwards the call to the one defined in the class, this way you can use your method in any instance of `Child` without having to put all the typeclass machinery.

I must say that this is useful for very high-level abstractions to which you plan to provide instances for many types *(even types outside your control like any of the standard collection types)* and write very generic functions that can operate on any of these.
If not, F-bounded types seems like the more rational solution.